# How to Collect a variable multiplied by a constant?

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, head

I'd like to use `Collect` to get terms that have a variable multiplied by a constant. For example I'd like:

```
Collect[x + b x, b x]
```

to give,`(1 + 1/b) b x`. However, it seems to ignore the variables that don't have the `Head` `Symbol`. 
I can find a workaround by using:

```
Collect[x + b x /. x -> xp/b, xp] /. xp -> b x
```

but is there a better (ideally more general) solution?

Comment: Yours is the most clear way i can think of.

Comment: Does this work with you `Collect[Expand [(x + b x)/b], x] b`?,

Comment: You might work with `CoefficientList[ expression , x] /b`, then manipulate the result to the form you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collect` is redundant for such cases.

```
Simplify[(x + b x)/b] b
```

> (1 + 1/b) b x

**Edit** To make sure, let's compare less trivial example `b x^2 + x + b x`:
`Collect` with `/.` fails to get the result:

```
 Collect[(b x^2 + x + b x) /. x -> xp/b, xp] /. xp -> b x
```

> (1 + 1/b) b x + b x^2

But `Simplify` can do the job:

```
Simplify[(b x^2 + x + b x)/b] b
```

> b x (1 + 1/b + x)

Note that even more dangerous `Collect` needs `Simplify` as an option in this case:

```
Collect[(b (x)^2 + x + b x)/(b x), x b, Simplify] (b x)
```

> b x (1 + 1/b + x)

**Edit2**
Also as Algohi notes:

```
Simplify @ Expand[(x + b x)/b] b
```

If you are sure that x is not zero, one may use it this way:

```
Simplify[(x + b x)/ (b x)] (b x)
```

or

```
Collect[(x + b x)/(b x) , x b] (b x)
```

Comment: `Collect` isn't doing anything in this case

Comment: @JeffDror, is there something wrong with the answer? Do you need only `Collect`-like solutions?

Comment: @garej: Thanks for your response. Your answer is very helpful, I've just been distracted. Thanks again!

Comment: @JeffDror, thank you for accept. Glad to help.